# Show that the integer nearest to $\frac{n!}{e}$ $(n \geq 2)$ is divisible by $n − 1$ but not by $n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

> Show that the integer nearest to $\frac{n!}{e}$ $(n \geq 2)$ is divisible by $n − 1$ but not by $n$.

I am still trying to improve my basic math skills but on this one i did not get far.

Taylor gives us $$e^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$

$$\frac{n!}{e} = n! \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$

Im guessing this is the right way to go but
can anyone give me a hint on whats the next step I should take?

Thanks.

Comment: The integer nearest $\frac{n!}{e}$ obeys a recurrence relation. See discussion at  https://oeis.org/A000166 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: This can be done in an elementary way. Every integral term is divisible by $n$ except for the last one, which is $1$. Every term except the last two are divisible by $n-1$. What are the last two terms?

Comment: Thanks both, now i have something to work on. @Matt Samuel

Comment: I assume that my comment was not what you were looking for, but was it helpful?

Comment: @Δαμον I dont know yet. Havent had time to digest the information on both those links yet.

Comment: @Δαμον But it looks promising at a first glance.

Comment: I have a guessing that the round sequence should like this : $b_{n}=nb_{n-1}+(-1)^n$

Comment: [This](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html) link is relevant, though it probably gives too much away.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Yes. Use the formula in your link, we can easily prove

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, the first five integers are : $0,1,2,9,44 $.

Then accoring to [Subfactorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html), we can imply this : $b_n=nb_{n-1}+(-1)^n$.

Under this guessing, we can prove $n|b_{n+1}$ inductively.

Assume $(n-1) |b_n$ and $n|b_{n+1}$, also :
$$
\begin{split}
b_{n+1}=(n+1)b_n+(-1)^{n+1}\\
b_{n+2}=(n+2)b_{n+1}+(-1)^{n+2}\\
\end{split}
$$
Add these two equations, we have:
$$b_{n+2}=(n+1)b_{n+1}+(n+1)b_n$$
Thus $(n+1)|b_{n+1}$

As for $n$ cannot divide $b_n$, it is because $b_n\equiv (-1)^n\mod n$

Comment: Nice answer. Yup.

Comment: Yes, thanks Benjamin!

Answer (score 2):

$$\text {For } n\geq 2, \text { we have }\quad n!/e=A+B+C$$  $$\text {where }\quad A=\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}(-1)^j [n(n-1)](n-2)!/j!$$   $$B=(-1)^{n-1}(n!/(n-1)!-n!/n!)$$   $$C=\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty} (-1)^jn!/j!$$  Now  $A=n(n-1)J$ where $J$ is an integer; while $B=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1),$  and $$|C|<\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty}(j+1)^{(-j+n)}=1/n\leq 1/2.$$ So $|C|<1/2$, and the nearest integer to $n!/e$ is $$A+B=n(n-1)J+(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)$$ which is divisible by $(n-1)$ and is congruent to $(-1)^n$ modulo $n$.